# How do I use summary() for rows only with a certain value in a column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to use summary() on an excel dataset which I imported into R. Want to create a conditional statement that only rows with a certain string in one of the columns are to be included.

New to R and programming in general, so please ELI5.

Best Regards,
Pontus

Comment: Please add reproducible example. Precise if you need help in excel or R ; the conditional statement has to be in excel o R ? Look at `dplyr::select_at()` in https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_all.html

Answer (score 0):

You can `summary` on a `subset`.  e.g.

```
summary(subset(mtcars, cyl == 4))
      mpg             cyl         disp              hp              drat             wt       
 Min.   :21.40   Min.   :4   Min.   : 71.10   Min.   : 52.00   Min.   :3.690   Min.   :1.513  
 1st Qu.:22.80   1st Qu.:4   1st Qu.: 78.85   1st Qu.: 65.50   1st Qu.:3.810   1st Qu.:1.885  
 Median :26.00   Median :4   Median :108.00   Median : 91.00   Median :4.080   Median :2.200  
 Mean   :26.66   Mean   :4   Mean   :105.14   Mean   : 82.64   Mean   :4.071   Mean   :2.286  
 3rd Qu.:30.40   3rd Qu.:4   3rd Qu.:120.65   3rd Qu.: 96.00   3rd Qu.:4.165   3rd Qu.:2.623  
 Max.   :33.90   Max.   :4   Max.   :146.70   Max.   :113.00   Max.   :4.930   Max.   :3.190
```